# How to stop a task initiated using NSOperationQueue?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsoperationqueue

[image]I have created a process using NSOperationQueue in the below way:

```
queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                           selector:@selector(loadDataWithOperation)object:nil];
[queue addOperation:operation];
[operation release];
```

In the `loadDataWithOperation` method I wrote code for printing infinite numbers.

Now I have called cancelAppOperations to stop its execution and also I have tried to set suspended value to YES like this

```
[queue setSuspended:YES]
```

even though the process is still running, I am calling the stoping method by using "stop"button. It is calling in the same class.

How can I stop it?

Comment: When are you calling cancel, and from where?

Answer (score 1):

You can send a cancellation message to all operations in the queue before they begin executing, but if your operation is already executing you need to process the cancel message

Comment: To expand more on this answer: An NSOperation subclass instance needs to check for its cancelation. If you are performing a network operation or a parsing/database operation, at some points of your execution, you need to check for the cancel property to check if the object has received a cancel operation. In other words, NSOperation wont cancel itself for you. This has to be done from within the NSOperation subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Here for suspend of queue 
                [queue setSuspended:YES]  is working fine,there I check the condition for stop the For loop i.e

```
if(![queue isSuspended]) 
{
        NSLog(@"elements are :%d",i);
}
else
{
    break; 
}
```

I placed these lines of code in  "loadDataWithOperation" method